# Multiple Java executables launch same application but different segments

Tags: java, sockets, process

I couldn't come up with a good name for this one, but basically what I want to do is something like LibreOffice. I am sure this is the same for many other applications (Firefox, Gimp). So what it does, you have multiple executables, say word processor and spreadsheets. When you launch Writer (LibreOffice word processor), it starts the application, when you start Calc (LibreOffice spreadsheets), it taggs along with Writer and just opens up another window with the different layout used to edit spreadsheets. It's all under this one process, `soffice.bin`. Every time you open another section of LibreOffice or another Writer window, you don't get any more processes, just windows. Same thing with Gimp, launching another instance, just brings the current one to focus, different concept but mostly programmatic the same. This could possibly be related to mobile devices, launching the app just brings the open one to focus, though I assume this is OS code doing that.

I am trying to do this in Java. I was thinking a lock file and then some sort of socket connection to communicate. Say Writer is open and you open Calc, it says, "Hey lock file is locked, let's open a socket and tell Writer that I want a Calc window". Obviously, Writer isn't open, it's the main process, but you get the idea.

Note I don't just want it to be, "Another instance of me already exists, `System.exit(0)`", but instead, "Another instance of me already exists, hey other instance, make another window! `System.exit(0)`"

Comment: It sounds like you already know exactly what you want to do. The first process creates a lock file and listens on a socket. The second process sees the lockfile and sends a message on a socket. The first process gets the message and creates a new window.

Comment: If you want to be really clever, you can write the port number into the lock file.

Comment: How do other applications do it? Check for another process with `ps` and then use some native thing to communicate? Or do they do the same thing with file locks and socket connections. I want to make sure this doesn't cause a performance issue and also make sure it is stable and work on all platforms. Will killing java with task manage or eclipse's kill java button leave the file locked? What operating systems have restrictions on opening up ports?

Comment: what's wrong with multiple processes anyway?

Comment: @bayou.io If they need to communicate a lot or it would be able to code much easier as one whole. For example, I am trying to code a whole software package that does everything from email, calendar, photo, contacts management, etc. The calendar would have events and events would have people, useful to integrate with contacts. Email would have contacts. And photos would have people in them associated with a calendar event. Because everything works together, it would make sense to use the same backend and save files while at the same time, not have all applications running at the same time.